# How to use remote desktop to a proxy server that's using Forefront TMG?

Tags: windows, desktop, proxy, remote

I need to get a proxy server going and I have a VM with Forefront TMG installed on it. Problem is that to access the proxy server (which I can't see, ping or access through the network) is only possible by accessing the host for the VM remotely (remote desktop) and then, through Hyper-V manager, connect to the proxy server. It's very slow to use.

Current situation:

> Me → VM Host → proxy server

Preferred situation:

> Me → proxy server

So, I want to use remote desktop to the proxy server directly, but the proxy server is all but invisible. Itself has connection to Internet, and the standard "WORKGROUP", but can't access the rest of our domain, like the other computers can.

I have tried to provide as much information about this as possible, but I'm an impossible newbie at this, so please be thorough in your answers.

Anything that helps me configure TMG is helpful.

Comment: I don't understand why the proxy server is not visible to the network... how do you plan to use it as a proxy server if you can't connect to it? (Perhaps it being invisible is not intended?)

Comment: It being invisible is not intended. I thought maybe it's something in Forefront TMG that makes it invisible to the network as a whole. Maybe I should add it to the domain.

Comment: So I made some adjustments in Windows itself and now I'm able ping the proxy server at least. I can't connect to it remotely yet and it doesn't show up in the network.

Comment: It seems like I should configure Forefront TMG:s firewall policies. Right now, it blocks a lot of traffice, regardless of what policies are in place.